# Want to change opacity with react native refs on click

Tags: react-native

Here is my code. I want to change the opacity of refs when i click on any TouchableOpacity component.Please guide me how i can change opacity or change colour in react native with refs. 
When i click my redirect function calls so i wanna change the opacity of particular ref in redirect function, i am passing ref and routename is redirect function.

i

```
mport React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  StyleSheet
} from 'react-native';
export default class Navigation extends Component {
  redirect(routeName,ref)
  {
      console.log(this.refs[ref]]);
      this.props.navigator.push({
      ident: routeName
     });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={style.navigation}>
        <View style={[style.navBar,styles.greenBack]}>
          <TouchableOpacity style={style.navPills} onPress={ this.redirect.bind(this,"AddItem","a")} ref="a">
            <Text style={[style.navText,style.activeNav]}>HOME</Text></TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity style={style.navPills} onPress={ this.redirect.bind(this,"AddItem","b")} ref="b">
            <Text style={style.navText}>ORDER</Text></TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity style={style.navPills} onPress={ this.redirect.bind(this,"ListItem","c")} ref="c">
            <Text style={style.navText}>SHOP LIST</Text></TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity style={style.navPills} onPress={ this.redirect.bind(this,"ListItem","d")} ref="d">
            <Text style={style.navText}>DUES</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        <View style={style.titleBar}>
          <Text style={style.titleBarText}>{this.props.title}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const style = StyleSheet.create({
 navigation:{
    top:0,
    right:0,
    left:0,
    position:'absolute'
  },
  navBar:{
    flexDirection:'row',
    padding:10,
    paddingTop:15,
    paddingBottom:15,
  },
  navPills:{
    flex:1,
    alignItems:'center'
  },
  navText:{
    flex:1,
    textAlign:'center',
    fontSize:16,
    fontWeight:'bold',
    color:'#ffffff',
    opacity:0.7
  },
  titleBar:{
    backgroundColor:'#ffffff',
    flex:1,
    padding:8,
    alignItems:'center',
    borderBottomWidth:1,
    borderBottomColor:'#dddddd'
  },
  titleBarText:{
    fontSize:18  
  },
  activeNav:{
    opacity:1
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not exactly sure if the following is what u are searching:

**If you want to change the opacity of the TouchableOpacity use the following**

```js
export default class Navigation extends Component {
  state={
    opacity: 0.1
  }
  
  handleOnPress = () => {
    this.setState({
      opacity: 0.5 //Anything u want
    });
  }
  

  render(){
    return(    
      <TouchableOpacity underlayColor={'rgba(0,0,0,this.state.opacity)'} onPress={this.handleOnPress}>
    )
  }
}
```

**If you want to change the opacity of your text use the following**

```js
export default class Navigation extends Component {
  state = {
    opacity: 0.1
  }
  
  handleOnPress = () => {
    this.setState({
      opacity: 0.5 //Anything u want
    });
  }
  

  render(){
    return(    
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.handleOnPress}>
       <Text style={[style.navText, {opacity: this.state.opacity}]}>DUES</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  }
}
```

*Using the Stylemethods in the render allows you to take variables from the state*

Hope this is the answer you wanted. If One of both is the right let me know and i delete the other one.

Best Regards

Comment: Thanks for ur reply Jonathan but i want to use react native refs for that. Like we use in jQuery to change the colour of particular text by passing the id of that text.
I want to use it for on click of particular TouchableOpacity if i give state then it will give same opacity to all components. thanks for ur help :)

Comment: okay :) sry for the missunderstood answer. Will delete this one. BR

Comment: What if I want to change it with a delay(no buttons involved)?

Comment: Can't you not just use the setTimeout() function from JavaScript for this at the place where you handle the opacity change? A description about how to use can be found in the following link: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Answer (score 0):

Put your opacity value into state.  Then make the button click change the value of that state.  This will trigger a re-render and your view will update with the new opacity.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the answer from pomo...

With the styles as you currently have them, you can easily call `setState` within each of your `onPress` functions to change the opacity of the elements you need changed. You don't even need to pass a reference if you utilize a different key in the state for each item.

Then, in your styles you would use an array of styles to use the opacity value from the state.

`style={[style.navPills, { opacity: this.state.opacityA }]}`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a fan of inline styles at all. So, for my purposes in a recent project I set the style of an element using its 'ref' value, then triggered a state change merely to cause the render function to be called. This is what I believe you're asking for and this sample code should point you in the right direction, otherwise perhaps this will help someone else in the future.

```
toggleDisplay() {
  if (this.refs.blah.style.display === "") {  // currently visible
    this.refs.blah.style.display = "none";
    this.setState({showBlah = false});
  } else {  // currently not visible
    this.refs.blah.style.display = "";
    this.setState({showBlah: true});
  }
}

render() {
  // Some element defined with the ref value used above.
  return (<div>
      <div ref="blah">Now you see me...</div>
      <button onClick="this.toggleDisplay">Toggle Me</button>
    </div>);
}
```

Nothing in my render function changed by adding the toggle functionality, other than adding a button somewhere to call the function.  As I already indicated, that state value is only used to trigger the render process.